# Alternative to FaceBook Social Plug-in Comments

Tags: facebook, openid, social-networking

I like the idea to add to my website a [Face Book Comment Plug-In](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/), this would allow my Users to comment and share my pages with their friends.

I understand this Plug-in come from Face Book and it is working with Anonymous User as for registers FB users.

What about other logged-in users like Google, Yahoo?

Albeit Face Book is quite popular I would like to know if exist some other free service out there that would allow commenting my pages from a wider range of registered users from other service like Google Account an Yahoo a bit similar to what OpenId provide for registering to a website.

Do you know any ideas?

Thanks for your time!

PS: Does FB support OpenId?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Disqus](http://www.disqus.com/). They integrate with Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo and OpenID.

> DISQUS is a comments platform that
>   helps you build an active community
>   from your website's audience. It has
>   awesome features, powerful tools, and
>   it's easy to install.

Comment: Yes, I have. To see it in action, take a look at Engadget or CNN.

Comment: Still using Disqus? Still happy with it?